# How to upload a website without an html files

Tags: html, web, upload, pug

H!
I have created a website, where all the files are of the type CSS, js, pug, and when I want to publish the site, I need to give an index.html file from which the site will start. The problem is that I do not have such a file.
Does anyone know how to deal with such a problem?
And in addition, I started the site by running it in localhost: 3000 does anyone know how to start it now so that it will work when I upload it.
Thanks in advance to all the helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mention of `localhost:3000` implies that you have written a website which depends on Node.js for server-side code (at a minimum this will involve the translation of your Pug templates into HTML on demand).

There are two general approaches you can take to solve this problem:

1. Find hosting which supports your server-side code and deploy your Node.js application to it. (This will **not** be typical static or shared hosting).
2. Generate static HTML documents from your application and upload those HTML documents. (The specifics will depend on exactly what your server-side implementation does and will probably be a significant amount of work. Typically if you wanted to take this approach, you would have used a [framework designed to output static sites](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/14/what-is-a-static-site-generator-and-3-ways-to-find-the-best-one/) from the outset).

Obviously if you have your server-side code processing user input (such as form submissions) option 2 will not work.

Comment: Ok, I will go with option 1. Thank you very much!